# Object Oriented Directory No Return?

Tags: java, directory

I'm working on an assignment that uses object oriented design for a directory lookup/database. I'm having trouble with my code not returning anything after I input the command and names. If someone can explain to me why this is happening, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Never close your standard in/out/error streams ;)

arg....doing this with a tablet stinks.

in your Directory#inDirectory method, your for loop never increments, so never completes.

Comment: I've removed the following code from DirectoryWithObjectDesign, however, it still does not return anything after input. I believe there's something wrong with my Directory.java, but I can't seem to find anything wrong with it.
    `stdin.close();
    d.closeDirectory();`

Comment: Sorry, i need to move to a computer...if you have no response by then, i'll assist.  Tablet formatting is impossible ;(

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and here is what I found.

Its throwing an "java.lang.IllegalStateException" in your  DirectoryWithObjectDesign class because you are trying to access the scanner which you have already closed .

Just add a break after your "d.closeDirectory();" command and your code should work fine .

Hope this helps!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class DirectoryWithObjectDesign {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String directoryDataFile = "D:/stackoverflow/StackJava/src/Directory.txt";
    Directory d = new Directory(directoryDataFile);
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Directory Server is Ready!");
    System.out.println("Available commands: find add delete");
    System.out.println("Format: command <name>\n" + "Enter ^Z to end\n");

    // Create/initialize the directory object
    // Tell the user the system is ready and waiting to execute commands
    while (stdin.hasNext()) {
        String command = stdin.next().trim();

        String name = stdin.next();
        System.out.println("command:" + command);
        System.out.println("name:" + name);

        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("find")) {
            if (d.inDirectory(name))
                System.out.println(name + " is in the directory");
            else
                System.out.println(name + " is NOT in the directory");
        } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            if (d.add(name))
                System.out.println(name + "has been added");
            else
                System.out.println(name + "is already in directory");
        } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
            if (d.delete(name))
                System.out.println(name + "has been deleted");
            else
                System.out.println(name + "is NOT in the directory");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please try again");
        }
        stdin.close();
        d.closeDirectory();
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My assignment requires the program to loop, therefore I can't use the break.

I found that I removed std.close(); it fixed the problem. However, I can't decipher why 'find' does not return anything nor can I enter anything else.

Comment: You for got to increment i in your Find method , add "i++" in your for loop. it going in to an infinite loop with mike mike mike mike  .....

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've should've seen that earlier!